# Snapping won't toggle, stuck on 'Increment' behavior

Tags: snapping, transform-orientation

Out of the blue, I have been encountering an odd behavior when using trying to switch between snapping modes. No matter what snapping mode is selected (Face, Edge, Vertex, Volume, etc), the snapping behavior remains stuck on that of 'Increment'.
Anyone out there ever run into the same issue and know of a fix?

So far I have tried reopening the file, as well as rebooting Blender, but to not avail. Opening up a different/new .blend file fixes the problem, however, so it does seem to be isolated to this file.

Thanks, J

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the blend file. But I guess you use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcut to activate the snapping.

If you uncheck the "Use Snap Translate" button, the Ctrl-snapping kinda fallback to incremental snapping :
[image]

Simply check the button again to fix it.

*I don't really know if this is a bug or an feature. If you left the "Use Snap Rotate" button unchecked, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while rotating will do incremental rotations (with 5° steps), which is quite useful. I guess the same logic is applied to translations.*